# How to hide LWC rich text field image icon from toolbar in Salesforce

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have a requirement to hide the standard Image icon on the rich text field. I have tried to hide it from CSS but that approach is not working. I would like to understand whether it's doable . If it's doable what kind of changes I need to make in my code.

**Html File**

```
<lightning-input-rich-text label="Case Comment" value={caseCmt} name='caseCmt' required="true">
</lightning-input-rich-text>
```

**CSS file**

```
lightning-input-rich-text > button > .slds-button.slds-button_icon-border-filled.ql-image

{
  
border:none;
  display:none;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable different toolbar categories using the `disabled-categories` attribute when defining the lwc-input-rich-input.

The category you'll need to remove the image icon would be ```INSERT_CONTENT````. This would remove the link button as well.

In this case, your component would look something like this:

```
<lightning-input-rich-text label="Case Comment" value={caseCmt} name='caseCmt' required="true" disabled-categories="INSERT_CONTENT">
</lightning-input-rich-text>
```

The details of how to customise the toolbar is under the Customizing the Toolbar section of the documentation for [input-rich-text](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-rich-text/documentation).

Comment: Thank you so much for the inputs. It was really helpful but this is disabling the link icon as well. Is there a way I can hide only Insert image icon alone?

Comment: I got it there is a format option were we can enable and disable particular icon from rich text tool bar.